# existe algum software que faça a analise de complexidade de um algoritmo?

Tags: java, algoritmo, recursão

existe algum software que faça a analise de complexidade de um algoritmo? se sim, gostaria de saber qual

Comment: Eu não vou garantir até porque para fazer algo parcial é possível e pode existir mas uma análise completa e que resolva todas situações é muito complicado ou impossível. Existem ferramentas que ajudam analisar.

Comment: JDepend - para java
NDepend - para .Net 
Analise ciclomatica do algoritmo

Comment: é um algoritmo simples, nada complexo, você pode citar quais são essas ferramentas?

Comment: Análise ciclomática não é complexidade de algoritmo. @JoseMaximilian não conheço nenhuma, estas que foram citas acima não faz isto que você quer, é outro assunto. Análise ciclomática é bem fácil de obter mas é algo muito simples. A proposta dela é analisar código e não algoritmo.

Comment: Posso ter entendido a pergunta errada, qual seria o intuito da pergunta? seria custo de execução do algoritmo? acredito que a análise ciclomática pode medir a complexidade do algoritmo depende do ponto de vista. Atualmente tenho um requisito de arquitetura que um método não poder ter mais que 5 pontos, e sempre chamei isso de complexidade do algoritmo.

Comment: @DouglasMendes [**Complexidade ciclomática**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_ciclom%C3%A1tica) nada tem haver com [**Complexidade algorítmica**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_computacional).

Answer (score 1):

Conheço duas boas opções que permitem uma análise estática de código e que incluem inclusive, a CC:
sonarqube e stan (http://stan4j.com/)